# Foursquare-async library errors

Tags: php, api, foursquare

I'm trying to use the [foursquare-async library](https://github.com/jmathai/foursquare-async) however I keep coming up against the following error (even when the testpage.php is ran which is written by the devs)

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp 
\www\EpiCurl.php on line 73 
Call Stack 
#       Time    Memory  Function        Location 
1       0.0005  694760  {main}( )       ..\simpleTest.php:0 
2       0.0024  971664  EpiFoursquare->get( )        ..\simpleTest.php: 
26 
3       0.0024  971744  EpiFoursquare->request( )    .. 
\EpiFoursquare.php:72 
4       0.0028  978720  EpiFoursquareJson->__get( )  .. 
\EpiFoursquare.php:0 
5       0.0028  979704  EpiCurlManager->__get( )     ..\EpiCurl.php:0 
6       0.0028  979704  EpiCurl->getResult( )        ..\EpiCurl.php: 
177
```

It would seem that the library is broken, or I'm being a mug

I hope you can help, this is rather getting on one's breasts

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the PHP script needs more time. You can start by increasing the PHP timeout value (php.ini => `max_execution_time`), and go from there.

Comment: I've increased it to 500 and still no luck, I doubt that this is the case